# SMOTE runs forever with no result (small dataset)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, smote, imblearn, oversampling

I'm trying to use SMOTE or SMONEENN on my dataset containing only 2000 rows. My set up is the following:

sklearn: '1.1.3'
imblearn: '0.9.1'
python: '3.10.8'

when running
`smt = SMOTEENN(random_state=42, n_jobs = -1, )`

and
`X_train_SMOTE, y_train_SMOTE = smt.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)`

the cell runs forever (i.e., I kill it after 1 hour) and it doesn't give me any results or an error.

Interestingly, during the loading, the CPU is not strained. Nothing seems to be happening.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I already reinstalled imblearn, but it didn't help.

Comment: maybe it is a bug when running in parallel, try to remove `n_jobs = -1`.

Comment: @JayPeerachai also didn't work without the n_jobs unfortunately.

Comment: How many columns are in the dataset? Edited nearest neighbors is an expensive algorithm, so there are situations where it can take quite a while.